# Looking for ways to create UML model from Java source

Tags: java, uml

What is the best way to document Java sources in UML? I know `class diagrams`, `package diagrams` and `object diagram`. What else should be documented? And is there any recommendation for a tool to support documentation?

Comment: I don't understand your question. "UML from java code" does mean what? Use Java to create UML (diagrams)?

Comment: sorry for my english, i want make diagrams from java code,
what any diagrams can i make from java code, i need guide reference for my work.

Comment: So you're trying to reverse engineer your Java code to get an UML model out of it?

Comment: I removed `relation diagram` from your question since there is no such diagram. Go for @xmojmr's answer. I guess GenMyModel is also worth a try.

Comment: oh thanks for revision.
yes, i think there is a best way.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [UML modeling tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools) with some kind of `code reverse engineering` support so that it can create some basic diagrams automatically from your existing code.

Creation of the rest requires manual work and some imagination and some thinking on your side. There's no magic tool. That would be your task/work/effort.

To find out what might the "*UML beside classes...*" browse through

- [uml-diagrams.org: UML Diagrams Examples](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html)
- [camunda.org: BPMN Examples, Patterns and Best Practises](http://camunda.org/bpmn/examples/)

Comment: no, i need make it manually, i want to know what any diagrams can i make from java code, and rules making for each of these diagram.

Comment: @uwong15 the `uml-diagrams.org` online book is probably the easiest `UML` book one can read and at the same time the most complete and up-to-date. To document your `Java` application, how does the code look ("structure diagrams") what does the code do ("behavior diagrams") and why ("use case diagram") **you can use all** of the available `UML` diagrams. For each diagram type the book contains examples, explaining chapter, drawing reference chapter and sometimes some discussion and historical background. After you know what's possible with pencil & paper, get a good `UML` modeling tool...

Comment: i not seem any examples that uml maked from java source, or may i cannot find it.
can u help me ???

Comment: @newbie which UML modeling tool do you use? Which Java IDE do you use? which OS do you use as your development platform?

Comment: i'm not using a tool, i want to make UML diagram manually. i wish i have complete tutorial how to make it.

Comment: @newbie I can somehow imagine what kind of `Java` code is hidden behind this [class diagram example](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/java-7-concurrent-uml-class-diagram-example.html?context=cls-examples) and this [sequence diagram example](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/spring-hibernate-transaction-sequence-diagram-example.html?context=seq-examples). Both were drawn using  "Microsoft Visio and UML 2.2 stencils" (not very rigorous/helpful `UML` tool). Pick an `UML` tool and read it's tutorials. It's probably the best I can advise you without seeing the real `*.java` code

Comment: very thanks for your help, it's little help for me.
but my part is to analyze real `*.java` and convert it to UML diagram manually.
sorry for my english.

Comment: @newbie in order to see how exactly should your manual result look like, you can use a tool like [ObjectAid UML Explorer for Eclipse](http://www.objectaid.com/), feed it with your `*.java` files, see what the tool draws and do the same (or similar) thing manually. There are about 20 [different types of  UML diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html) and all of them can describe your real `*.java` code. Just start drawing and if you hit some concrete drawing obstacle related to some concrete piece of code then open another question

Comment: i have e-book in here [link](http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy252/references/UML_for_Java_Programmers-Book.pdf). i need more references to support my project please.

Comment: @newbie I don't understand what kind of references or support you need for your project, neither what is your project about, how large etc. **I did start** with `UML` drawing for real by downloading evaluation version of `Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect`, loading my existing code into it using the [Source Code Reverse Engineering](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.0/software_engineering/reverseengineersourcecode.html) feature, reading it's tutorial example model and starting to draw something useful around my own code base. Then my employer purchased a license

Comment: so, i need examples java code, then create UML diagram from that codes.

Comment: @newbie yes, it is one way how to learn things practically. If you have some code already. In order to learn it from the other end, playing with trial version of the [Astah UML modeling tool](http://astah.net/) can be also  useful and their paper [Modeling in the Agile Age](http://cdn.astah.net/resources/modeling-in-the-agile-age.pdf) may explain a few things to you as the book you have linked above is some 12 years old. **start**-somehow-anyhow

Answer (score 2):

From Java code, you can get the class diagram including relationships (relation diagram does not exist). Object diagram is for describing runtime instances.

If you have your Java code in a Git repository, you can get the corresponding UML model online using the GenMyModel reverse engineering feature ([get started](https://github.com/Axellience/customgen-documentation/blob/develop/reverse-gettingStarted.md), [documentation](https://github.com/Axellience/customgen-documentation/blob/develop/reverse.md)).